# Adding to linked list struct using a while loop doesn't save the data (IN C)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, while-loop, linked-list

This is one of my first questions so I hope I formulate it well. I checked some other similar questions on StackOverflow but I got no real answers from them. I have the following struct:

```
struct process {
int priority;
char* path;
char* parameters;
struct process *next;
};
```

I am reading each line from a file and adding the string tokens I get in my struct linked list using a while loop. Here is the adding method:

```
struct process * add(int prio,char* pat, char* par,  struct process *head) {
  struct process *new_node;
  new_node = ( struct process *) malloc(sizeof( struct process));
  new_node->priority = prio;
  new_node->path = pat;
  new_node->parameters = par;
  new_node->next= head;
  head = new_node;
  return head;
}
```

So the main algorithm gets the lines from a file using fgets in a while loop :

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
```

then I tokenize all the strings I need and use the add method to add them to my linked list. I convert the first string to int to respect the types.

This is my while loop and main algo :

```
        FILE *file = fopen(filename , "r");
    char line[124];
    // can be put outside and passed as argument.
    struct process *head = ( struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process));
    new_node->priority = prio;
    new_node->path = pat;
    new_node->parameters = par;
    new_node->next= head;
    char* priority,*path,*parameters;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
         priority=strtok(line," ");             
         // The fix here is the following :
         char *path_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
         path = malloc(strlen(path_token) + 1); 
         strcpy(path, path_token);
         char *par_token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
         parameters = malloc(strlen(par_token) + 1);
         strcpy(parameters, par_token);
         // End of edit Thanks to the answers bellow
         char* junk;
         int p = strtol(priority,&junk,10);
         printf("prio : %d  ",p);
         head = add(p, path, parameters,head);
         printf("\n");
         pront(head);
         printf("\n");
    }
    \\ free the mallocs
```

We notice here that I use the pront() method to print my linked list at every step. I also do it after my while loop. Here is the code for pront():

```
void pront(struct process *head) {
struct process *current_node = head;
while ( current_node != NULL) {
    printf("%d , %s , %s ", current_node->priority, current_node->path, current_node->parameters);
    printf("\n");
    current_node = current_node->next;
}
```

}

the method prints nonsense :

```
prio : 2  
2 , ./printchars , a 12 b 

prio : 15  
15 , ./printchars , c 23 d 
2 ,  ,  

prio : 7  
7 , ./printchars , e 34 f 
15 , /printchars ,  34 f 
2 , ./printchars , e 34 f
```

it is supposed to print :

```
7 , ./printchars , e 34 f 
15 , ./printchars , c 23 d 
2 , ./printchars , a 12 b
```

I am sure that the problem comes from the while loop since when using the adding method outside of the loop and then printing, I get valid results. But as soon as it gets in the loop, the Head linked list doesn't store the values properly! 
Thanks for the help

EDIT : The issue is fixed and the issue was my awfully wrong use of strtok and pointers to char's without malloc. Lesson learned !

Comment: `head = NULL;`... Doing this inside the algorithm you provided just after you `malloc()`-ed it... is in fact, flat out wrong!

Comment: @Ruks I do this to make sure the linked list is empty at the start of the process. removing it doesn't change anything except that I have an additional object with null values (that I don't want).

Comment: No!, you should not use `head = NULL;` for that! [`memset(head, 0, 1);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) is the way... You are trying to leak the object by assigning `NULL` to it!

Comment: However, it's wrong. `struct process *head = ( struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process));` allocates memory and stores it's address in `head`. `head = NULL;` overrides `head`. Now, the just allocated memory is lost - it's a memory leak.

Comment: `path` and `parameters` are pointers. What are they pointing at? Do `path` and `parameters` from different `struct process` point at different places? What are these places?

Comment: @Ruks I would prefer `memset(head, 0, sizeof *head);` ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I tried using memset(head, 0, sizeof *head);, However, the algorithm prints the same junk plus this :  0 , (null) , (null).

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the
corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments.*

Comment: @n.m. path and parameters and char pointers, I use them the same way I would use a char array. This is close to a string.

Comment: That's wrong. A `char*` can point to a string but you have to provide the storage. A `char[]` provides storage. That's the difference.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the help, Yes the issue is here. I will try to figure a solution out!

Comment: That's the pity with strings in C, especially when input. You have to provide storage beforehand but you don't know how much. A simple solution: use a local buffer (array) for input with an appropriate limit. After input into this buffer has succeeded, determine size with `strlen()` **+ 1**, allocate sufficient memory (with `malloc()`, storing address into `char*`), `strcpy()` buffer to that memory. In the past, there was `strdup()` for this purpose but I recently realized that it seems not to be part of the standard library. (Why not?) However, it's simple to resemble...

Comment: @Scheff Yeah this is what I have just done and fixed my Issue, I know a bit about strdup() but I am not really comfortable in C. It's a bit outside of my comfort zone and I am too rusty right now :D. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked list does not store the values at all.

The issue isn't the loop, but [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) - you are using it incorrectly: it does not allocate memory to save the tokens it parses, but instead uses a single internal static buffer.

So, to save the values, you must allocate memory for your strings (`path` and `parameters`) and use `strcpy` to copy the strings to the allocated memory.
Remember to `free` each item fields before freeing list items!

Example:

```
char *path_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
path = malloc(strlen(path_token) + 1); /* remember to allocate space for \0 terminator! */
strcpy(path, path_token));
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with below code.

```
new_node->priority = prio;
new_node->path = pat;
new_node->parameters = par;
```

Your structure has a character pointer for `path` and `parameters`

What you are doing here is just assigning the pointer in the structure to the pointer in the function, passed. Later on when `pat` or `par` changes value or has some garbage value, the structure element will also have garbage value.

What you need to do is to allocate memory for each element and `strcpy` the data

Additionally, as pointed out by @Ruks -

```
struct process *head = ( struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process)); 
head = NULL;
```

is wrong. You are loosing the pointer returned by `malloc`. If you want to ensure that the linked list is empty initially, you should initialise all elements of `head`.

```
head-> priority = 0; 
head-> path = NULL;
head-> parameters = NULL;
head-> next = NULL;
```

Comment: I'm trying a solution right now with what you suggest here! I'll be back in 5!